# returning the rowID for an PDO update query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

How would i get the rowID for an update query (i am of course not updating by rowID)
The below code is what i am using (as a public function within a Class), but of course using "lastInsertId()" is not working for me (i didnt really expect it to work and it returns 0)

```
$query = "UPDATE tSecurityDepositPaymentAddresses
                SET
                    tGuardians_GuardianID = ?
                WHERE tGuardians_GuardianID = 0
                LIMIT 1";                   
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array($GuardianID));             
        return $db->lastInsertId();
```

Could i combine the update query within a nested select? or is there a simpler way?

sorry if my question sounds bumb, but im still learning...

Thanks

Comment: there is no *the* row id as the update could apply to a couple of rows

Comment: Also, MySQL doesn't have row IDs.